# C# Refactoring Many For loops to one

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Good evening guys, I just start learning C# and doing some tasks. So the question is:
I have created an 2D arry lets say int[5,5] and i need to alter any array as this : the value 0 in the elements on the left side of the main
diagonals, 1 - on the right. 
any array should looks like this.
So I wrote a code, but it seems I have to refaktor it, but I don't know how. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
int[,] someArray = new int[5,5];
newMatrix(someArray);
int row = someArray.GetLength(0);
int col = someArray.GetLength(1);
for (int i = 1; i < row; i++)
{
   someArray[i, 0] = 0;
}
for (int i = 2; i < row; i++)
{
     someArray[i, 1] = 0;
}
for (int i = 3; i < row; i++)
{
     someArray[i, 2] = 0;
}
for (int i = 4; i < row; i++)
{
     someArray[i, 3] = 0;
 }
 for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
 {
     someArray[0, j] = 1;
 }

  for (int j = 2; j < col; j++)
  {
      someArray[1, j] = 1;
  }
   for (int j = 3; j < col; j++)
  {
      someArray[2, j] = 1;
  }
  for (int j = 4; j < col; j++)
  {
       someArray[3, j] = 1;
  }
```

`

Comment: Exemple: `{{22,1,1,1,1}, 
  {0,33,1,1,1},
  {0,0,44,1,1},
  {0,0,0,55,1},
  {0,0,0,0,66}}`

Comment: @MikeKasian I'm not sure that your example if right one, where do you get 22/33/etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on [CodeReview.se] instead.

Comment: With that said, with regards to your question, try this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_nested_loops.htm

Comment: Sorry gues  I did try to find an answer and but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd refactor it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<col; j++)
        if (i == j)
            someArray[i, j] = ?; // main diagonal
        else
            someArray[i, j] = (j > i) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but now I have to find main diagonal, if I am right?

Comment: @MikeKasian no, you need to decide what value should be put into main diagonal's elements

Comment: Yes Its works THANK YOU, I get it about diagonal just now )